# Why does my CSS code renders incorrectly on iOS/MacOS?

Tags: ios, macos, vue.js, safari, vuejs3

We developed a web app on **Vue 3** and it displays perfectly on every browser except on iOS and Mac OS devices.
This is worse if you're using Safari, however some issues occur even on Chrome for Mac.
This problem causes forms to always be shown blank, without displaying a placeholder or user input. It also makes several other elements to misalign.

We even tried making a new form and removing all stylesheets, but the problem persists.

Here is the code for one of the forms:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="contactus" @submit.prevent="saveMessage">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="titleFormAbout">
          {{ $t("contactus.componentForm.text1") }}
        </h1>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 30px;">{{ $t("contactus.componentForm.text9") }}</p>
      <input type="text"  class="form-control formContact" :placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text2')" id="name" required />
      <input type="email"  class="form-control formContact" :placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text3')" id="email" required />
      <vue-tel-input
        v-model="phone"
        id="phone"
        class="formControl formContact"
      ></vue-tel-input>
      <br />
      <textarea
        class="form-control formContact"
        name=""
        id="message"
        rows="10"
        :placeholder="$t('contactus.componentForm.text5')"
        required
      ></textarea>
      <br />
      <vue-recaptcha  
        style="margin-bottom: 14px" 
        @validate="validated"
        />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input
            class="form-control "
            type="Submit"
            id="submitButton"
            :value="$t('contactus.componentForm.text6')"
            disabled
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <button class="form-control clear" @click="clearForm" >
            {{ $t("contactus.buttonClear") }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <div class="alert" id="Response" role="alert"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import VueRecaptcha from "../forms/vue-recaptcha.vue";
const hostName = location.port =="" ?location.protocol + "//" + location.host:'http://'+location.hostname+':3000';

export default {
  components: {
    VueRecaptcha,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      config: {
        headers: {
          //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validated(){
      const htmlElement=document.getElementById('submitButton');
      htmlElement.classList.add('submit');
      htmlElement.disabled=false;
    },
    clearForm() {
      document.getElementById("name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("email").value = "";
      document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].value = "";
      document.getElementById("message").value= "";
    },
    saveMessage() {
      //alert(document.getElementsByClassName("highlighted")[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML)
      const responseBox = document.getElementById("Response");
      const params = new FormData();
      const countryPhone = document.getElementsByClassName("highlighted");
      var countryPhoneid = "+52";
      if (countryPhone.length > 0) {
        countryPhoneid =
          countryPhone[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
      }

      params.append("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
      params.append("email", document.getElementById("email").value);
      params.append("phone",countryPhoneid + " " + document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].value);
      params.append("message", document.getElementById("message").value);
      axios
        .post(hostName + "/api/contact", params, this.config)
        .then((response) => {
          responseBox.innerHTML = this.$t("contactus.componentForm.text7");
          responseBox.classList.add("alert-success");
          setTimeout(() => {
            responseBox.classList.remove("alert-success");
          }, 5000);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          responseBox.innerHTML = this.$t("contactus.componentForm.text8");
          responseBox.classList.add("alert-danger");
          setTimeout(() => {
            responseBox.classList.remove("alert-danger");
          }, 5000);
          console.log(err);
        });
      responseBox.hidden = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        responseBox.hidden = true;
      }, 5000);
      document.getElementById("name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("email").value = "";
      document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].value = "";
      document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].placeholder=this.$t('contactus.componentForm.text10');
    const listcountry = document.getElementsByClassName("vti__dropdown-list");
    listcountry[0].getElementsByTagName("li")[137].classList.add("highlighted");
    document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0].required = true;
    document
      .getElementsByName("telephone")[0]
      .addEventListener("input", (textin) => {
        const telephone = document.getElementsByName("telephone")[0];
        //console.log(parseInt(textin.data));
        //console.log(Number.isInteger(textin.data));<
        if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(textin.data))) {
          //  console.log(telephone.value);
        } else {
          telephone.value = telephone.value.slice(
            0,
            telephone.value.length - 1
          );
        }
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.contactus .submit {
  background: #008b9e;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contactus .formContact{
    border: 2px solid #BAD1FF;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
}
.contactus .clear {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contactus .titleFormAbout {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #00a8c6;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 12px;
  text-transform: none;
}
form.contactus {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  padding-right: 5vw;

}
.contactus form li {
  color: black;
}
.contactus .alet {
  text-align: center;
}

.contactus .contactus p{
  text-align: justify;
}
</style>
```

**Here you can see the type of behaviour we're getting:**

**On iOS/MacOS:**

[image: Text wrongly displayed on Apple devices] [image: Form wrongly displayed on apple devices]

**The same elements on Windows/Android devices:**

[image: Text displayed properly on Windows and Android] [image: Form displayed properly on Windows and Android devices]

Can anyone please tell me if this is a common issue and if there's a solution? We have been stuck with this problem for two weeks and we're losing our minds.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try first using a normalize.css globally so that all browsers have the same default styles? Did you try adding browser specific css prefixes?

Comment: "some issues occur even on Chrome for Mac" - it remains unclear which part is Safari problem and which is Apple. In case this is style problem, can you provide a way to reproduce with plain layout (no Vue)? If it's not, did you check the console for errors? The question doesn't have good chances to be answered in its current form.